# Using SED to delete colon to end of line after IPv4 address match

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

The script matches private IP in file and prints the 3rd column.

The value in the 3rd column can be either IPv4 or IPv6.  The IPv4 address is trailed by a ":PORT".  I can run `sed 's/:.*//g'` but this will also impact the IPv6 address if printed.   Likewise if I use mutiple FS [,:] it will print the IPv4 but only the first octet of the IPv6 address.

My solution is to strip the ":PORT" from the end of the IPv4 address

```
$ cat openvpn-status.log
10.13.0.27,ijegunbead-4,74.201.72.222:49911,2022-06-26 02:55:26
10.13.0.23,biddy-h-1,2803:4600:1111:17ec:a821:1a8:53ca:760d,2022-06-26 02:55:28
```

I have this running in a while loop, one cycle dst will `== 10.13.0.27`,  the next `== 10.13.0.23`

```
dst1=$(egrep -w ^$dst /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log | awk -F'[,:]' '{print $3}')
```

Result:

```
74.201.72.222
2803
```

Desired Result:

```
74.201.72.222
2803:4600:1111:17ec:a821:1a8:53ca:760d
```

I tried this but no luck

```
dst1=$(egrep -w ^$dst /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log | awk -F',' '{print $3}') | sed 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:*//g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
$ awk -F, '$3~/\./{sub(/:.*$/,"",$3)}{print $3}' openvpn-status.log
74.201.72.222
2803:4600:1111:17ec:a821:1a8:53ca:760d
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution employing `sed` solution as requested in question title, let `file.txt` content be

```
10.13.0.27,ijegunbead-4,74.201.72.222:49911,2022-06-26 02:55:26
10.13.0.23,biddy-h-1,2803:4600:1111:17ec:a821:1a8:53ca:760d,2022-06-26 02:55:28
```

then

```
cut --delimiter=',' --field=3 file.txt | sed '/^[0-9]*[.]/ s/:[0-9]*$//'
```

gives output

```
74.201.72.222
2803:4600:1111:17ec:a821:1a8:53ca:760d
```

Explanation: use cut to get 3rd field from ,-delimited file, then for every line which starts with zero-or-more digits followed by literal dot replace : and zero-or-more digits adjacent to end of line by empty string i.e. delet it

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*

Answer (score 1):

1. 

```
# perl -MRegexp::Common=net -F, -lanE  'say $& if $F[2] =~ /$RE{net}{IPv4}|$RE{net}{IPv6}/g' file 
74.201.72.222        
2803:4600:1111:17ec:a821:1a8:53ca:760d
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566517/grep-regular-expression-that-matches-all-valid-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses

https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common

2.

```
# awk -F, '{if($3~/\./){gsub(/:/,",")}; print $3}'  file          
74.201.72.222        
2803:4600:1111:17ec:a821:1a8:53ca:760d
```